# Processing multiple files effectively XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdf, compiling, performance

I need to effectively compile many .tex files to .pdf. As far as I know, LaTeX (so XeLaTeX too) takes a lot of time for loading itself to memory, but a *compilation process* is fast. Now I have a program which calls XeLaTeX *every time for every .tex document*, so it takes a lot of time for loading compiler every time.

I also tried to found something like TeX Daemon, which could be called when it need and could produce .pdf very fast, but I only found this old project: https://github.com/brianmhunt/texd

Are there any methods for preloading TeX compiler to memory or some daemonds?

Comment: you might want to look at `mylatex` (or the extended version of that `mylatexformat`) to make a custom format if all your documents share a common preamble